# Prove $n+1$ vectors in $P_n(\Bbb{F})$ with the specific condition is not linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Let $p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n$ is polynomials in $P_n(\Bbb{F})$ such that $p_i(2)=0$ for every $i\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$. Prove that $p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n$ is not linearly independent in $P_n(\Bbb{F})$.

I saw that $p_0(x)=0$ if we want $p_0(2)=0$, since one vector is zero vector ,then that vectors is linear dependent. What do you think about this proof?

Comment: Why $p_0 = 0$? Maybe something about $p_j$ is missing?

Comment: if $p0\not=0$ then you have $p0=a$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ if you put p0(2)=a so that does not belong to that vectors that i write $p(2)=0$,

Comment: Then some assumptions about $p_j$ are missing. Please edit your question and add them.

Comment: Did you see that I put that for every polynomials $p(2)=0$ can you write some polynom such that $p_0(2)=0$? Write that polynom and prove that is zero for 2

Comment: @MarkoŠkorić How about $p_0(X)=X^5-32$ (assuming $n\ge 5$)?

Comment: The reply above assumes that $\deg(p_0) = 0$ which is not mentioned in your post. So your question is not with sufficient background. For general polynomials, $p(x) = (x-2)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial always works.

Comment: I think that p0(x) means that this degree of polynoms is zero so p0(x)=a where $a\in \mathbb R$

Comment: Is this specified in your question? I did not see that.

Comment: I get question like that I write so sorry if something is hard to understand

Comment: If that is the case, then your attempt is unjustified at the very begining. Follow the hint by Hagen von Eitzen below. .

Comment: yes I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $i \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, since $p_i(2) = 0$ there exists $q_i \in P_{n-1}(\mathbb{F})$ such that $p_i(x) = (x-2)q_i(x)$.

We have $\dim P_{n-1}(\mathbb{F}) = n$ so the set $\{q_1, \ldots, q_n\} \subseteq P_{n-1}(\mathbb{F})$ is linearly dependent. Therefore, there exists scalars $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{F}$ not all equal to $0$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i q_i(x) = 0$.

Then $$\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_ip_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i (x-2)q_i(x) = (x-2) \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i q_i(x)\right) = 0$$

so $\{p_0, \ldots, p_n\}$ is linearly dependent in $P_n(\mathbb{F})$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose it is linearly independent, then it forms a basis for $P_n$, since $\text{dim}(P_n)=n+1=\Big\vert \{p_0,p_1,...,p_n\} \Big\vert$

> Is all members of $P_n$ are  in $\text{Span}\{p_0,p_1,...,p_n\}$ ?
>
> Answer: (Think about constant polynomials)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\dim P_n=n+1$, hence $n+1$ linearly independent vectors would be a bassis and hence span all of $P_n$.